# Loading scss with require causes bootstrap 4 variables to be overwritten

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

Using create-react-app

Loading scss file condionally:

```
  componentDidMount(): void {
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_APPID == 'sw') {
          require('../sw.scss');
    }
  }
```

sw.scss:

```
$primary: #7e8dbb;
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

This works when in devmode (`yarn serve`)

But on build (`yarn build`) the variables ($primary etc) is overwritten.

If I instead do a "normal" `@import` of the scss file in top of the file, it works. But as far as I know, I must use require to conditionally load a scss file.

Any ideas? Any alternative way to conditionally load a scss file?

Comment: CSS rules dictate that `@import` at-rules must be placed prior to any other statement. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import). I wonder if the parsing of the SCSS variable is causing your problem here?

Comment: No according to bootstrap4 docs the variables should be stated before the @import of bootstrap.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, that is correct. However, SCSS variable assignment does not result into a CSS statement. Therefore the `@import` rule will be first.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - that makes sense. Thanks.